# Error inserting in SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to create the following database:

```
public static final String KEY_NAME = "nombre";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";

private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table capas (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                            + "id text not null, "
                            + "nombre text not null);"
        + "create table poi (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                            + "id text not null, "
                            + "nombre text not null, "
                            + "lon real not null, " 
                            + "lat real not null, "
                            + "info text, "
                            + "email text, "
                            + "telefono text, "
                            + "web text, "
                            + "usuario text, "
                            + "capas_id text not null);"
        + "create table mensajes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                            + "id text not null, "
                            + "mensaje text not null, "
                            + "fecha text not null, "
                            + "poi_id text not null, "
                            + "usuario text not null);";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "upv_db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_CAPAS = "capas";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_POIS = "poi"; 
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_MENSAJES = "mensajes"; 
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

There're three tables in it. These are the methods to initialize, create and retrieve rows from the first table (I haven't written the methods for the other 2 tables yet):

```
   public long createCapa(String id, String nombre) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_ID, id);
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, nombre);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_CAPAS, null, initialValues);
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor over the list of all notes in the database
     * 
     * @return Cursor over all notes
     */
    public Cursor leerCapas() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_CAPAS, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_ID, KEY_NAME}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    //Inicializa la tabla de capas por defecto
    public void inicializaCapas(){
        createCapa("cap001", "Escuelas");
        createCapa("cap002", "Departamentos");
        createCapa("cap003", "Edificios");
    }
```

The app is not working because it gets an error when inserting in the DB. This is the error in the log:

```
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743): Error inserting nombre=Escuelas id=cap001
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1549)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at com.android.upvar.DatosDB.createCapa(DatosDB.java:131)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at com.android.upvar.DatosDB.inicializaCapas(DatosDB.java:180)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at com.android.upvar.menu.listaCapas(menu.java:52)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at com.android.upvar.menu.onCreate(menu.java:46)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-23 20:39:14.354: ERROR/Database(743):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 20:39:14.394: ERROR/Database(743): Error inserting nombre=Departamentos id=cap002
.
.
.
```

So it complains about some constraint violation, but I don't see any of those. The only constraints are the primary keys and they are set to be autoincrement, so I don't understand what it is complaining about.

Comment: Have you looked at the table values? My guess, is that you have somehow called that initialize method twice.

Comment: I've just checked so, and it's only called once. The initialization method is called when the Activity is created (onCreate).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried all your suggestions during these 2 days and I appreciate them. But you know what? When I started Eclipse today, I run the app and I just worked out. I have no idea how, because yesterday when I finished trying it didn't work. But surprisingly it's fixed.

I'm quite happy about that, but also concerned, because that makes me feel the app is not reliable. Does these things happen usually in Android or in SQLite? Has it happened to you before? If you have some advice, please share it, because maybe it will stop working suddenly some other day,  who knows?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I think of with "constraint failed" is that something is either being inserted a NULL or you're missing a column.  Nothing is being inserted as NULL in that example, and the only missing column is an autoincrement primary key.

However, unless you indicate it in some way, the database and tables are not recreated on each test.  Could you be testing on a device that has an older version of those tables in it, one where the "_id" column was not autoincrement?  If so, it's expecting ContentValues to also contain a value for that column.

Answer (score 0):

Hm...try this idea:

Have you tried to allow writing to the database before you do the writing? `SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE`?

Like

`mDb=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);`?

Comment: I'm not using that method, but I do tell the DB when opening it that it is possible to write with:
    public DatosDB open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

Comment: Hmm...Try with this. I had situations when `.getWritableDatabase()` does not return what I wanted.

Comment: Ok, but when I created the DB in this way I didn't specify where was it going to be stored. So what PATH do I use?

Comment: If you create the database before you call this method, the database path should be in `data/data/yourpackagename/database/DATABASENAME`

Comment: And with this way you are accessing the database, not creating. Creation suppose to be done before  using this method. I hope it works.

Comment: Add another line intialValues.put("_id", "?"); ? I don't see any constrains in your db definition. But look for IF YOU PASS NULL to a field which is defined to be NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Android, so this could be off, but it appears you're sending the ID with the insert into CAPAS table, but it's unnececessary because you have it defined as AUTOINCREMENT.

You have:

```
public long createCapa(String id, String nombre) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_ID, id);
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, nombre);

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_CAPAS, null, initialValues);
}
```

What happens if you do this?

```
 public long createCapa( String nombre) {
     ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    //initialValues.put(KEY_ID, id);
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, nombre);

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_CAPAS, null, initialValues);
  }
```

and this:

```
     createCapa("Escuelas");
```

Is it really common practice to define both _id and id in Android?  When you define the pk as integer primary key in SQLite it becomes an alias for the rowid automatically.  Here's how I would do it normally:

```
       create table capas (id integer primary key autoincrement, nombre text not null);
```

Comment: The data comes from a remote MySQL database, where id's are VARCHAR. I don't want to miss that id, but I need to use CursorAdapter, so that's why I use _id integer autoincrement as the primary key in this DB. That's the reason I'm keeping both. Anyway, I tried to remove the id field and insert just the name, but it gives the exact same error.

Comment: Is KEY_ID a constant Android uses to identify the PK column? You are assigning a string to the column this constant points to. `public static final String KEY_ID = "id";`

Comment: No, KEY_ID is not being used by Android as primary key. The primary key that android is using is KEY_ROWID, which will be an integer. Sorry for the confusion this is causing, but KEY_ID is not being used as primary key.

Answer (score 0):

YOU can try this it worked for me when i was getting same error for no reason

```
return mDb.insertWithOnConflict(DATABASE_TABLE_CAPAS, null,
  initialValues,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```