# How i call method to insert data in SQLite

Tags: android, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error inserting in SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802362/error-inserting-in-sqlite-database)

Hi.............
         I am new for Android, right now i am working with android database. I want to insert some hard-coded value in my database , by call a method.

```
     public void insertdata(String ti, String de) {
    ContentValues userdetailValues = new ContentValues(); 
    userdetailValues.put("tick", ti);
    userdetailValues.put("des",de);
    dh.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, userdetailValues);
    }
```

Above method is define in a activity out on onCreate() block. When i am going to call this method within onCreate() block as

```
 insetdata(aaa,bbb);
```

Then it show a error for me-

```
    aaa can not be resolve to variable and same for bbb.
```

As i told that i am new for Android , and quite afraid, in that case if it is small issue , then please help me ,i am just a learner .
Thanks in Advance to all.

Comment: Is that a typo? Is it **insertdata** or **insetdata** ?

Comment: there are several example for database Insertion, Updation & Deletion.... [1. Android SQLite with ContentProvider](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) [2. Android Sqlite with Video Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11951088/1160282)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone Number

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing string value in function so try with double quote or create aaa and bbb string variable and assign some value in it.

```
insetdata("aaa","bbb");
```

or

```
String aaa = "test", bbb = "testy";
insetdata(aaa,bbb);
```

**Edit -** you need to initialize your **dh** object and open database before inserting value and close it after use it.

Comment: Nothing related with type casting, `aaa can not be resolve to variable` tells that variable not declared or out of scope

Comment: @hotveryspicy you are right that is why i told him to declare variable . do you notice my answer carefully or just downvote on base of my first soulution.

Comment: Yes .... i did as you both suggest me. But still i am getting Null pointer Exception

Comment: @user1734491 in which line you find null pointer exception ?

Comment: and   dh.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, userdetailValues);

Comment: @user1734491 have you initialized dh object ?

Comment: Yes ... you tooooooo gooood .... It is initialized issue. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You might be having problem with these lines

```
userdetailValues.put("tick", ti);
userdetailValues.put("des",de);
```

instead of using "tick" and "des" use column names where you have to add the data . Your code can be like

```
 public void insertdata(String ti, String de) {
ContentValues userdetailValues = new ContentValues(); 
userdetailValues.put(DatabaseHelper.C1, ti);
userdetailValues.put(DatabaseHelper.C2,de);
dh.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, userdetailValues);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because the variable you are passing to the function is not valid in that scope.
Did you try inserting any hard-coded values.

Like:

```
  insetdata("aaa","bbb");
```

Comment: I already try this one bur it shows NULL POINTER EXCEPTION for me... Thanks for response. Plz help me

Comment: Did you try creating helper and datasource classes for doing the database transactions?